# Error - <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected string or buffer

Tags: ckan

I am having real problems with CKAN. Everytime I try and access the datasets within my instance of CKAN 2.7 running on Ubuntu I get an internal server error which starts off

Error - : expected string or buffer

I also get the same error if I try and add a dataset. Any assistance wold be most appreciated as I am out of ideas.

The full log message I get is:

```
Error - <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected string or buffer
URL: http://155.245.98.207/
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weberror/errormiddleware.py', line 171 in __call__
  app_iter = self.application(environ, sr_checker)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
  resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **self.kwargs)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 208 in call_func
  return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fanstatic/publisher.py', line 234 in __call__
  return request.get_response(self.app)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1053 in get_response
  application, catch_exc_info=False)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1022 in call_application
  app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 147 in __call__
  resp = self.call_func(req, *args, **self.kwargs)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/dec.py', line 208 in call_func
  return self.func(req, *args, **kwargs)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/fanstatic/injector.py', line 54 in __call__
  response = request.get_response(self.app)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1053 in get_response
  application, catch_exc_info=False)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py', line 1022 in call_application
  app_iter = application(self.environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/middleware/pylons_app.py', line 205 in inner
  result = application(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py', line 73 in __call__
  return self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beaker/middleware.py', line 155 in __call__
  return self.wrap_app(environ, session_start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/routes/middleware.py', line 131 in __call__
  response = self.app(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 125 in __call__
  response = self.dispatch(controller, environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/wsgiapp.py', line 324 in dispatch
  return controller(environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/lib/base.py', line 297 in __call__
  res = WSGIController.__call__(self, environ, start_response)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 221 in __call__
  response = self._dispatch_call()
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 172 in _dispatch_call
  response = self._inspect_call(func)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 107 in _inspect_call
  result = self._perform_call(func, args)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylons/controllers/core.py', line 60 in _perform_call
  return func(**args)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/controllers/home.py', line 56 in index
  context, data_dict)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/__init__.py', line 431 in wrapped
  result = _action(context, data_dict, **kw)
File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/get.py', line 1865 in package_search
  package_dict = json.loads(package_dict)
File '/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py', line 338 in loads
  return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File '/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py', line 366 in decode
  obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer


CGI Variables
-------------
  CKAN_CURRENT_URL: '/'
  CKAN_LANG: 'en'
  CKAN_LANG_IS_DEFAULT: True
  CONTENT_LENGTH: '0'
  HTTP_ACCEPT: '*/*'
  HTTP_HOST: '155.245.98.207'
  HTTP_LANGUAGE: 'en'
  HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'pk'
  PATH_INFO: '/'
  REMOTE_ADDR: '185.35.63.152'
  REQUEST_METHOD: 'GET'
  SERVER_NAME: '0.0.0.0'
  SERVER_PORT: '80'
  SERVER_PROTOCOL: 'HTTP/1.1'


WSGI Variables
--------------
  application: <fanstatic.publisher.Delegator object at 0x7faadcfea150>
  beaker.cache: <beaker.cache.CacheManager object at 0x7faadcfea050>
  beaker.get_session: <bound method SessionMiddleware._get_session of <beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware object at 0x7faadcf00d10>>
  beaker.session: {'_accessed_time': 1497372408.247228, '_creation_time': 1497372408.247228}
  ckan.app: 'pylons_app'
  fanstatic.needed: <fanstatic.core.NeededResources object at 0x7faab491aad0>
  paste.cookies: (<SimpleCookie: >, '')
  paste.httpserver.thread_pool: <paste.httpserver.ThreadPool object at 0x7faae64ab950>
  paste.registry: <paste.registry.Registry object at 0x7faab413b050>
  paste.throw_errors: True
  pylons.action_method: <bound method HomeController.index of <ckan.controllers.home.HomeController object at 0x7faaaff0ecd0>>
  pylons.controller: <ckan.controllers.home.HomeController object at 0x7faaaff0ecd0>
  pylons.environ_config: {'session': 'beaker.session', 'cache': 'beaker.cache'}
  pylons.pylons: <pylons.util.PylonsContext object at 0x7faaaff0ef90>
  pylons.routes_dict: {'action': u'index', 'controller': u'home'}
  repoze.who.api: <repoze.who.api.API object at 0x7faab445a350>
  repoze.who.logger: <logging.Logger object at 0x7faadd054dd0>
  repoze.who.plugins: {'ckan.lib.authenticator:UsernamePasswordAuthenticator': <ckan.lib.authenticator.UsernamePasswordAuthenticator object at 0x7faadcf00b50>, 'friendlyform': <FriendlyFormPlugin 140371906939664>, 'auth_tkt': <CkanAuthTktCookiePlugin 140371905678864>}
  routes.route: <routes.route.Route object at 0x7faadcf97110>
  routes.url: <routes.util.URLGenerator object at 0x7faab491a4d0>
  webob._parsed_query_vars: (GET([]), '')
  webob.adhoc_attrs: {'response': <Response at 0x7faab491aa90 200 OK>, 'language': 'en-us'}
  wsgi process: 'Multithreaded'
  wsgiorg.routing_args: (<routes.util.URLGenerator object at 0x7faab491a4d0>, {'action': u'index', 'controller': u'home'})
------------------------------------------------------------
2017-06-13 17:46:48,266 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  / render time 0.016 seconds
```

The schema xml file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->

<!--
     NB Please copy changes to this file into the multilingual schema:
        ckanext/multilingual/solr/schema.xml
-->

<!-- We update the version when there is a backward-incompatible change to this
schema. In this case the version should be set to the next CKAN version number.
(x.y but not x.y.z since it needs to be a float) -->
<schema name="ckan" version="2.3">

<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="tdates" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="7" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
    <fieldType name="booleans" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tints" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloats" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tlongs" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tdoubles" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" positionIncrementGap="0" multiValued="true"/>

    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>


    <!-- A general unstemmed text field - good if one does not know the language of the field -->
    <fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>


<fields>
    <field name="index_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="site_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="entity_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="dataset_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="state" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="revision_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="version" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="ckan_url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="download_url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" />
    <field name="notes" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="author" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="author_email" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="maintainer" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="maintainer_email" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="license" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="license_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="ratings_count" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="ratings_average" type="float" indexed="true" stored="false" />
    <field name="tags" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="groups" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="organization" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <field name="capacity" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <field name="res_name" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="res_description" type="textgen" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="res_format" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="res_url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="res_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- catchall field, containing all other searchable text fields (implemented
         via copyField further on in this schema  -->
    <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="urls" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>

    <field name="depends_on" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="dependency_of" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="derives_from" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="has_derivation" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="links_to" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="linked_from" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="child_of" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="parent_of" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="views_total" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <field name="views_recent" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <field name="resources_accessed_total" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <field name="resources_accessed_recent" type="int" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

    <field name="metadata_created" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <field name="metadata_modified" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <field name="indexed_ts" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>

    <!-- Copy the title field into titleString, and treat as a string
         (rather than text type).  This allows us to sort on the titleString -->
    <field name="title_string" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" />

    <field name="data_dict" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />
    <field name="validated_data_dict" type="string" indexed="false" stored="true" />

    <field name="_version_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <dynamicField name="extras_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="res_extras_*" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="vocab_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*" type="string" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>
</fields>

<uniqueKey>index_id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>

<copyField source="url" dest="urls"/>
<copyField source="ckan_url" dest="urls"/>
<copyField source="download_url" dest="urls"/>
<copyField source="res_url" dest="urls"/>
<copyField source="extras_*" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="res_extras_*" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="vocab_*" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="urls" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="text" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="license" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="notes" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="tags" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="groups" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="organization" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="res_name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="res_description" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="maintainer" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="author" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="capacity" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="metadata_modified" dest="date"/>

</schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that the `package_dict` returned by SOLR is not JSON, and it needs to be.

- Are you using the recommended SOLR version?
- Have you tried reindexing all the datasets? `paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild --config=/etc/ckan/std/std.ini`

If this doesn't work then I suggest you dig into see what's happening when the error occurs in `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/logic/action/get.py`. See what's the value of `package_dict` and `data_source`, using pdb or print statements, running ckan using paster.